# How to use “interest” in questions?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

The classical question in English when we use the word “interest” is:

1. Are you really so interested in that book that you are going to buy it?

I wonder if the following constructions are ok?

2. Is this book interest you so much that you will buy it?
3. Did you take so much interest in the book that you are going to buy it?
4. Do you interest so much in this book that you will buy it?

Comment: #2 is syntactically invalid (the auxiliary verb should be ***Does** it interest you so much...?*). #3 is syntactically valid, but no native speaker would be likely to say it. #4 is syntactically invalid, and there's no obvious simple way to *make* it valid. But this all just looks like Off Topic proofreading to me.

Comment: We say _the book interests me_, but not _I interest in the book_.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that in English, *interest* works "backwards" from the way similar verbs do in other languages.  We don't say "I interest in the book", we say, "The book interests me" (active) or "I am interested in the book" (passive).

Answer (score 1):

(2) Is incorrect. It should be: "Does this book interest you so much that you will buy it?"

(3) Appears to be correct but sounds somewhat unnatural. "Have you taken" is more natural than "Did you take"

(4) Is incorrect, it should be: "Do you **have so much interest** in this book that you will buy it?"

Generally, in this context, to sound more natural, it is better to use 'are you going to', rather than 'will' (as in example 3):

e.g. "Does this book interest you so much that you **are going to** buy it?"

Comment: #4 could also be "**Are you so interested** in this book..."